# Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Tags: php, angular, docker, slim

I'm currently developing a service-based system and having some problems with the http requests(seems to be a problem with CORS - Cross origin resource sharing).

The API where I'm sending the request is written in PHP, with the Slim framework and I'm actually enabling CROS with the following code:

```
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

But when I send requests from the front-end(written with Angular):

```
this.http.get(this.base_url + "api/users/")
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
name:"HttpErrorResponse"

message:"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
```

The two projects are running in Docker, if that's adds an information.

Does anyone has any idea where the problem could be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does your network tab look like in your browser?

Comment: Response heard:

Accept-Ranges bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *
Connection  keep-alive
Date  Mon, 15 Jan 2018 19:26:42 GMT
ETag  W/"5fe-uNDg6SbGwTj25EJmji4p+X0nqF0"
X-Powered-By Express


If that's what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

it is usually 500 code internal server error for this case.

Similar causes:

```
1. Server (API) not running or disconnected
2. Your api code has problem
3. You specify wrong url
```